# Why when I try to .clone() a hangout it doesn't appear?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api, google-hangouts

Here's my codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjxrmO

HTML:

```
<button>Create a new hangout</button>
<hr />
<div id="container">
  <p id="hello">hello</p>
<div id="hangout" class="g-hangout" data-render="createhangout"></div>

</div>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
   console.log('hello world');
     $('p').clone().appendTo('#container');
    $('#hangout').clone().appendTo('#container');
  });
});
```

I'm confused why I when I try to $('p').clone().appendTo('#container') the paragraph clones as expected when the button is clicked on, but the  does not clone.

Comment: Ah sorry, jQuery was not saved when I added it. Saved it now. Question remains.

Comment: UPDATE: http://codepen.io/lindapeng/pen/WQaZeJ

Answer (score 1):

The `<div id="hangout">` doesn't remain in the DOM as it was written within the original markup.

As Google's API sets up the Hangout button, it alters or replaces the element:

```
<div id="___hangout_0" style="...">
```

So, when the `.click` event occurs, there is no longer an element with `id="hangout"` for the `#hangout` selector to match.

```
$('button').click(function () {
  console.log( $('#hangout').length ); // 0
});
```

To be able to clone it, you'll have to adjust the selector to match the `id` that's being set.

```
$('#___hangout_0').clone().appendTo('#container');
```

---

You can also create a new `<div>` and render it as a button [using `gapi.hangout.render()`](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button#render_button_using_html5_markup).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var hangouts = 0;

  $('button').click(function () {
    $('#hello').clone().appendTo('#container');

    var hangout = $('<div>').appendTo('#container').get(0);
    gapi.hangout.render(hangout, { 'render': 'createhangout' });
  });
});
```

Comment: If you want to clone elements shouldn't use ids as selectors, use classes instead.

Comment: @DaveGomez In this case, the element isn't left with a `class` to select it by (despite starting with one -- `class="g-hangout"`). Otherwise, I'd certainly agree.

Comment: Sorry Jonathan, my comment was for LNA. Your solution is fine 